# How can I compile all .thrift files (*.thrift) as a Maven phase?

Tags: maven, ant, thrift

I'm using maven-antrun-plugin to execute a thrift shell command. I can compile one file per `<exec>` with `<arg value="...path/to/file.thrift" />`, but I would like to compile all `.thrift` files in a directory. How can I do this?

I tried using `<arg value="...path/to/*.thrift" />`, but Maven rejected this syntax.

Comment: Is it possible to generated python/other language files, or it can only generated java files?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The are several options to compile thrift files in maven project:

### Option 1: Use maven thrift plugin (the best one)

Maven Thrift plugin supports generation of sources/test sources, recompile on modify, etc. Basically, it's the most convenient way to use thrift in Maven project.

1. Put your sources in `src/main/thrift` (or `src/test/thrift` for test thrift sources).
2. Install the thrift binary to /usr/local/bin/thrift (or any other place, you prefer)
3. Add the plugin to the `plugins` section of your pom.xml:

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.thrift.tools</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-thrift-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>0.1.11</version>
           <configuration>
               <thriftExecutable>/usr/local/bin/thrift</thriftExecutable>
           </configuration>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>thrift-sources</id>
                   <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>compile</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                   <id>thrift-test-sources</id>
                   <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>testCompile</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```

That's it: next time you call `mvn compile` java sources will be generated from thrift. Generated sources will be placed into `target/generated-sources/thrift/` directory, and this directory will be added to the compile path for java compiler.

You can find the detailed instructions, samples and more on the Github: https://github.com/dtrott/maven-thrift-plugin.

### Option 2: Use Maven Antrun plugin

If it's necessary for some reason to use antrun plugin, it's better to use `apply` command instead of `exec` to process a set of files.

I'll write only a basic idea of ant target, since conditional recompilation on modification is probably out of scope of this question:

```
<target name="compile-thrift">
    <!-- Define fileset of thrift files -->
    <fileset id="thrift.src.files" dir="${src.thrift.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.thrift"/>
    </fileset>

    <!-- Invoke thrift binary for each of these files -->
    <apply executable="${thrift.compiler}" resultproperty="thrift.compile.result"
    failifexecutionfails="true" failonerror="true"
    searchpath="true" dir="${src.thrift.dir}">
        <arg value="-o"/>
        <arg value="${thrift.dest.dir}"/>
        <arg value="--gen"/>
        <arg value="java"/>
        <srcfile/>
        <fileset refid="thrift.src.files"/>
    </apply>
</target>
```

### Option 3: Use antrun with exec ant task

If it's absolutely necessary for some reason to use Antrun plugin and `exec` task, there's a way to do so. I'd advise against it, since it's ugly and not portable, but it might work. Use `xargs` to invoke Thrift compiler for a list of files:

```
<exec dir="${src.thrift.dir}" executable="bash">
  <arg line="ls * | xargs ${thrift.compiler} -o ${thrift.dest.dir} --gen java"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: I'd like to Xlint my handwritten .java code, while not Xlinting my thrift-generated .java code. Could you tweak your solution to accomplish this?

Comment: While using maven-thrift plugin, I was getting this error:nknown option java:hashcode(thrift: 0.11.0). Does anybody else face the same issue? I searched over net, says: it doesn't have java:hashcode option anymore. Downgrading to thrift 0.9.3 worked for people. But I wanted to use this or latest version only, any suggestions?

Comment: @Wildfire Is there way to avoid reference to **thriftExecutable** ? I want that maven downloadloads that generator on startup. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044010/how-to-use-thrift-generator-as-maven-dependencyhow-to-avoid-reference-to-exe-f

Answer (score 10):

I'm playing aground with thrift 0.10.0 and found that in order to use maven-thrift-plugin I had to provide `generator` option:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.thrift.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-thrift-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <thriftSourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/resources/thrift</thriftSourceRoot>
                <generator>java</generator>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>thrift-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>thrift-test-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Otherwise it would complain that "unknown option java:hashcode". In fact, seems that there's no such option in java generator any more. `thrift --help` gives these options:

```
  java (Java):
beans:           Members will be private, and setter methods will return void.
private-members: Members will be private, but setter methods will return 'this' like usual.
nocamel:         Do not use CamelCase field accessors with beans.
fullcamel:       Convert underscored_accessor_or_service_names to camelCase.
android:         Generated structures are Parcelable.
android_legacy:  Do not use java.io.IOException(throwable) (available for Android 2.3 and above).
option_type:     Wrap optional fields in an Option type.
java5:           Generate Java 1.5 compliant code (includes android_legacy flag).
reuse-objects:   Data objects will not be allocated, but existing instances will be used (read and write).
sorted_containers:
                 Use TreeSet/TreeMap instead of HashSet/HashMap as a implementation of set/map.
generated_annotations=[undated|suppress]:
                 undated: suppress the date at @Generated annotations
                 suppress: suppress @Generated annotations entirely
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing. This solved my issue. Adding <generator>java</generator>

Answer (score 0):

> Is there way to avoid reference to thriftExecutable ? I want that
> maven downloadloads that generator on startup. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044010/how-to-use-thrift-generator-as-maven-dependencyhow-to-avoid-reference-to-exe-f))

`maven-thrift-plugin` usually requires you to install Thrift compiler in the build server as it requires to reference its path in `<thriftExecutable>`.

For people who don't want to do that and if your build server is already installed with docker runtime , another option is to compile it using a docker image that is already created and shared by people such as [this one](https://hub.docker.com/r/cspwizard/thrift). So ,

### Option 4: Use Docker Image

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.42.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <images>
            <image>
                <name>cspwizard/thrift:0.18.1</name>
                <run>
                    <platform>linux/amd64</platform>
                    <volumes>
                        <bind>
                            <volume>src/main/resources:/data</volume>
                            <volume>src/main/java:/out</volume>
                        </bind>
                    </volumes>
                    <cmd>--gen java -out /out -v -r /data/build.thrift</cmd>
                </run>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This configuration assumes you put all the .thrift file in `src/main/resources/data`. `build.thrift` is the main entry file which you need to manually include all .thrift that you want to compile :

```
include "foo.thrift"
include "bar.thrift"
include ........
```

It needs to do that simply because the thrift compiler does not support specifying a list of .thrift file to be compiled. (see [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3013) for more info).